# how to inject multiple JdbcOperations into Spring Test Case

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-batch, spring-test

Here is my Code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/load-BMS-data-job-launcher-context.xml" })
public class SimpleJobLaunchFunctionalTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplateBMS;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource BMSdataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplateBMS = new JdbcTemplate(BMSdataSource);
    }   

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE from SHADOW_BMS");
     // jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE from CMNREF.CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V");
        jdbcTemplateBMS.update("DELETE from CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V");
```

I want to wire two separate JdbcTemplates to operate on two distinct databases inside this test class.   I fail to know how to set different dataSources - I get an exception when I try to invoke the second setDataSource(DataSource BMSdataSource) method.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create beans with name="template1" and name="template2" (with annotations @Bean(name = "template1") ). In the test you use them as follows:

```
@Qualifier("template1")
@Autowired
private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate1;

@Qualifier("template2")
@Autowired
private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate2;
```

Comment: Thank you - I thought I had to invoke the setDataSource(DS ds) twice:  once for each jdbc tmplate... but they are already pre-wired with datasource.    Thanks again.